# Is there a difference between protected class methods and private class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, private, encapsulation, protected

I'm trying to understand the difference between private class methods and protected class methods in Ruby in terms of accessibility. I've provided a code example that I am using to study the difference:

```
class Aclass 
    #public methods below
    def self.accessprivatemethodfromwithinsameclass
        privatemethod 
    end 

    def self.accessprotectedmethodfromwithinsameclass
        protectedmethod
    end 


class << self
    private
        def privatemethod
            "I'm a private method" 
        end 
        
    protected 
        def protectedmethod
            "I'm a protected method" 
        end 
    end
end 

class ASubClass < Aclass
    class << self 
        def accessprivatemethodfromwithinsubclass
            privatemethod
        end 

        def accessprotectedmethodfromwithinsubclass
            protectedmethod
        end 

    end
end 


#Example 
Aclass.protectedmethod 
Aclass.privatemethod
Aclass.accessprivatemethodfromwithinsameclass
Aclass.accessprotectedmethodfromwithinsameclass
ASubClass.accessprivatemethodfromwithinsubclass
ASubClass.accessprotectedmethodfromwithinsubclass
ASubClass.privatemethod
ASubClass.protectedmethod
```

So far I've concluded that:

- Both are accessible from within the class ie. as in `self.accessprivatemethodfromwitinsameclass` and `self.accessprotectedfromwithinsameclass`
- Both are not accessible from outside the class as in `Aclass.protectedmethod` and `Aclass.privatemethod`.
- Both are accessible from within the subclass see `access...methodwithinsubclass`.
- However both cannot be directly called within the subclass. see `ASubclass.private/protectedmethod`.

The only difference in behaviour is that when they are not accessible the protected method says:

> NoMethodError: protected method ... called for ...Class

where the private method says:

> NoMethodError: private method ... called for ...Class.

My question is as follows:
is there ever a case where there is a difference in behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are no class methods in Ruby

The first important concept to understand is that *there is no such thing as a class method* in the Ruby Object Model. We *talk* about class methods colloquially, and there are even methods in the Ruby core library which refer to class methods (e.g. [`Module#public_class_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-public_class_method) and [`Module#private_class_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method)), but *fundamentally*, in the Object Model, they don't exist.

What we *call* a class method is actually just a normal *singleton method* like any object can have it. It's just that the object happens to be an instance of the class [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Class.html). But fundamentally, there is no difference between a singleton method of an object that is an instance of `Foo` and an object that is an instance of `Class`.

The reason we use a special name for the latter is that they are very common, and "singleton method of an object that happens to be an instance of `Class`" is a mouthful, so we say "class method" instead.

## There are no singleton methods in Ruby

The second important concept to understand is that *there is no such thing as a singleton method* in the Ruby Object Model either! We *talk* about singleton methods colloquially, and there are even methods in the Ruby core library which refer to singleton methods (e.g. [`Object#singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_method), [`Object#singleton_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_methods), or [`Object#define_singleton_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method)), but *fundamentally*, in the Object Model, they don't exist.

What we *call* a singleton method is actually just a normal *instance method* of the [*singleton class*](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class). But it's a bog standard instance method, there is nothing special about it. It's the singleton *class* that is special, not the *method*. But fundamentally, there is no difference between an instance method that is defined in any other module and a singleton method that is defined in a singleton class.

The reason we use a special name for the latter is that it is useful to distinguish them, and "instance method of a module that happens to be a singleton class" is a mouthful, so we say "singleton method" instead.

Likewise, "instance method of a module that happens to be a singleton class of an object that happens to be an instance of `Class`" is a mouthful, and so way say "class method" instead.

## Message accessibility in Ruby

However, since we now know that class method are just singleton methods and singleton methods are just instance methods (and in fact, there is only one kind of method in Ruby, instance methods, no singleton methods, no class methods, no static methods, no constructors), we can simply look at message accessibility in Ruby in general, since we know that there is nothing special about class methods.

Ruby has three message accessibility levels:

- `public` (the default)
- `private`
- `protected`

### Aside: where is this defined?

Unfortunately, unlike many other programming languages, the Ruby Language Specification does not exist as a single document in a single place. Ruby does not have a single formal specification that defines what certain language constructs mean.

There are several resources, the *sum* of which can be considered kind of a specification for the Ruby programming language.

Some of these resources are:

- The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) – Note that the ISO Ruby Specification was written around 2009–2010 with the specific goal that all existing Ruby implementations at the time would easily be compliant. Since YARV and MacRuby only implement Ruby 1.9+ and MRI only implements Ruby 1.8 and lower and JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, and IronRuby (at the time) only implemented a subset of Ruby 1.8, this means that the ISO Ruby Specification only contains features that are common to both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9. Also, the ISO Ruby Specification was specifically intended to be minimal and only contain the features that are absolutely required for writing Ruby programs. Because of that, it does for example only specify `String`s very broadly (since they have changed significantly between Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9). It obviously also does not specify features which were added after the ISO Ruby Specification was written, such as Ractors or Pattern Matching.
- [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) – Note that the `ruby/spec` is unfortunately far from complete. However, I quite like it because it is written in Ruby instead of "ISO-standardese", which is much easier to read for a Rubyist, and it doubles as an executable conformance test suite.
- [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) – This book was written by David Flanagan together with Ruby's creator matz to serve as a Language Reference for Ruby.
- [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/) – This book was the first English book about Ruby and served as *the* standard introduction and description of Ruby for a long time. This book also first documented the Ruby core library and standard library, and the authors donated that documentation back to the community.
- The [Ruby Issue Tracking System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/), specifically, the [*Feature* sub-tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/issues?tracker_id=2) – However, please note that unfortunately, the community is really, really bad at distinguishing between Tickets about the Ruby Programming Language and Tickets about the YARV Ruby Implementation: they both get intermingled in the tracker.
- The Meeting Logs of the [Ruby Developer Meetings](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14770). (Same problem: Ruby and YARV get intermingled.)
- New features are often discussed on the [mailing lists](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/), in particular the [ruby-core (English)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-core/index.shtml) and [ruby-dev (Japanese)](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-dev/index.shtml) mailing lists. (Same problem again.)
- The [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/) – Again, be aware that this documentation is generated from the source code of YARV and does not distinguish between features of Ruby and features of YARV.
- In the past, there were a couple of attempts of formalizing changes to the Ruby Specification, such as the [Ruby Change Request (RCR)](http://rcrchive.net/) and [Ruby Enhancement Proposal (REP)](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/Ruby_Enhancement_Proposals) processes, both of which were unsuccessful.
- If all else fails, you need to check the source code of the popular Ruby implementations to see what they *actually* do. Please note the plural: you have to look at multiple, ideally *all*, implementations to figure out what the consensus is. Only looking at one implementation *cannot possibly tell you* whether what you are looking at is an implementation quirk of this particular implementation or is a universally agreed-upon behavior of the Ruby Language.

### `public`

`public` is easy: it has no restrictions. Done.

### `private`

The rule for `private` accessibility is also very simple: a message send can only invoke a private method if

- the message send has an implicit [receiver](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver) (`some_private_method`) OR
- the explicit receiver is the [*literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`*](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/keywords_rdoc.html) (`self.some_private_method`).

It is *not* enough that the receiver is `self`! For example, this is not allowed:

```ruby
foo = self
foo.some_private_method
```

The receiver *must* be either implicit or it must be the *literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`*.

The reason for this restriction is that [the implementors of Ruby implementations with highly-sophisticated, aggressively optimizing compilers wanted to be able to *statically* determine whether a message send was allowed to invoke a private method or not](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907#note-9). If you relax this rule to say "a private method can be invoked if the receiver is `self`", then you can no longer statically determine this, see the following example:

```ruby
foo = if rand < 0.5 then self else some_other_object end
foo.some_private_method
```

This is what section 13.3.5.3 *Private methods* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) has to say:

> ## 13.3.5.3 Private methods
>
> A private method is a method whose visibility attribute is set to the private visibility.
>
> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation, except for a method invocation of any of the following forms where the *primary-expression* is a *self-expression*.
>
> - *single-method-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-method-assignment*
> - *single-indexing-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-indexing-assignment*

Note that the ISO Ruby Programming Language Specification has not been updated since 2012, so this is a slightly outdated definition. The specification was slightly simplified a couple of years ago. Nowadays, the second paragraph should probably read more like this:

> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation, except for a method invocation where the *primary-expression* is a *self-expression*.

But note that this doesn't make a difference here, since in your code you are not using a *self-expression* as the receiver anyway, so whether a *self-expression* is allowed in a limited number of cases or always is irrelevant.

The [ruby/spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/) for [`private`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/private_spec.rb) and for [message sends](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/send_spec.rb) also does not seem to be fully up-to-date, but again, the differences do not matter for your question.

The RDoc for [Modules](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html), specifically, the [subsection on Visibility](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Visibility), however, is fully up-to-date and pretty clear:

> The third visibility is private. A private method may only be called from inside the owner class without a receiver, or with a literal `self` as a receiver. If a private method is called with a receiver other than a literal `self`, a `NoMethodError` will be raised.

### `protected`

In order to be allowed to invoke a `protected` method, the *sender* needs to be an instance of the module the *invoked method* is defined in.

In other words, if you have a `protected` method `m` defined in module `M` like this:

```ruby
module M
  protected def m; end
end
```

Then `m` can only be invoked by a message send where the sender is an instance of `M`:

```ruby
kind_of?(M) #=> true
M === self  #=> true

receiver.m
```

So, in other words, in order for

```ruby
some_object.some_protected_method
```

to succeed,

```ruby
kind_of?(some_object.method(:some_protected_method).owner)
```

or

```ruby
some_object.method(:some_protected_method).owner === self
```

must be `true`.

[Note: I am assuming that `Object#method`, `Method#owner`, `Module#===`, and `Object#kind_of?` have not been monkey patched or overridden. The check is *not* guaranteed to be performed using those actual methods, it is typically performed using internal knowledge by the implementation. In other words, you can't override the behavior of `protected` by monkey patching or overriding those methods.]

Here's what section 13.3.5.4 *Protected methods* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) has to say:

> ## 13.3.5.4 Protected methods
>
> A protected method is a method whose visibility attribute is set to the protected visibility.
>
> A protected method can be invoked if and only if the following condition holds:
>
> - Let *M* be an instance of the class `Module` in which the binding of the method exists.
>   *M* is included in the current self, or *M* is the class of the current self or one of its superclasses.
>
> If *M* is a singleton class, whether the method can be invoked or not may be determined in an implementation-defined way.

And the RDoc:

> The second visibility is `protected`. When calling a protected method the sender must inherit the `Class` or `Module` which defines the method. Otherwise a `NoMethodError` will be raised.
>
> Protected visibility is most frequently used to define `==` and other comparison methods where the author does not wish to expose an object’s state to any caller and would like to restrict it only to inherited classes.

## Your examples

Now, let's apply what we learned above to your examples:

> So far I've concluded that:
>
> - Both are accessible from within the class ie. as in `self.accessprivatemethodfromwitinsameclass` and `self.accessprotectedfromwithinsameclass`

The classes are irrelevant here. All that matters is the sender and receiver (for `protected`) or just the receiver (for `private`).

`privatemethod` works, not because it is "within the same class", but because the receiver is implicit.

`protectedmethod` works, not because it is "within the same class", but because the sender and the receiver are both the same object (the sender is *always* `self`, the receiver in this case is implicit, and the implicit receiver is always `self`), so it is trivially true that the sender is an instance of the receiver's type.

> - Both are not accessible from outside the class as in `Aclass.protectedmethod` and `Aclass.privatemethod`.

Again, the classes don't really matter here.

`Aclass.privatemethod` doesn't work, not because it is "outside the class", but because the receiver is neither implicit (i.e. `privatemethod`) nor the literal pseudo-variable keyword `self` (i.e. `self.privatemethod`).

`Aclass.protectedmethod` doesn't work, not because it is "outside the class", but because the sender (in this case the un-named top-level object typically called `main`, which is a direct instance of `Object`) is not an instance of the module the method is defined in (in this case `Aclass.singleton_class`).

> - Both are accessible from within the subclass see `access...methodwithinsubclass`.

Again, the subclass is irrelevant here. In fact, these two cases are exactly identical to the first and second cases from your first bullet point.

`privatemethod` works, not because it is "within the subclass", but because the receiver is implicit.

`protectedmethod` works, not because it is "within the subclass", but because the sender and the receiver are both the same object (the sender is *always* `self`, the receiver in this case is implicit, and the implicit receiver is always `self`), so it is trivially true that the sender is an instance of the receiver's type.

> - However both cannot be directly called within the subclass. see `ASubclass.private/protectedmethod`.

Again, the subclass is not really relevant here. In fact, these two cases are *exactly identical* to the third and fourth cases from your second bullet point before.

`ASubclass.privatemethod` doesn't work, not because it is "outside the class", but because the receiver is neither implicit (i.e. `privatemethod`) nor the literal pseudo-variable keyword `self` (i.e. `self.privatemethod`).

`ASubclass.protectedmethod` doesn't work, not because it is "outside the class", but because the sender (in this case the un-named top-level object typically called `main`, which is a direct instance of `Object`) is not an instance of the module the method is defined in (in this case `Aclass.singleton_class`).

## A more interesting example

```ruby
class Superclass
  class << self
    protected def protected_method; end
  end
end

class Subclass < Superclass
  Superclass.protected_method
end
```

Is this allowed or not? (Spoiler alert: the answer will first appear to disappoint you, but then satisfy you nonetheless.)

Well, let's check. Remember the rule for `protected`: the *sender* must be an instance of the module the *invoked method* is defined in.

So, the module the invoked method is defined in, is `Superclass.singleton_class`, i.e. the singleton class of the object `Superclass`.

The *sender* is the object `Subclass`.

So, the question is: is the object `Subclass` an instance of the class `Superclass.singleton_class`? The answer to this is non-obvious.

Clearly, `Subclass` is a subclass of `Superclass`. But that doesn't help us.

Also, clearly, both `Subclass` and `Superclass` are instances of `Class` (`Subclass.class == Class` and `Superclass.class == Class`), which also means they are instances of all of `Class`'s superclasses `Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, and `BasicObject`. But that doesn't help us either: the sender must be an instance of the module *the invoked method is defined in*. It doesn't matter how many *other* modules the sender and the receiver have in common in their ancestry, they need to specifically have *this* module in common (in this case `Superclass.singleton_class`)

Also, by the definition of what the singleton class is, `Superclass` is an instance of `Superclass.singleton_class` and `Subclass` is an instance of `Subclass.singleton_class`. But that doesn't help us either, since what we would need is for *`Subclass`* to be an instance of *`Superclass.singleton_class`*.

So, it looks like the answer is: No, this is not allowed.

Except, when you try it out, then it works! But, why?

Maybe you have already spotted the "escape hatch" when I quoted section 13.3.5.4 *Protected methods* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html):

> ## 13.3.5.4 Protected methods
>
> A protected method is a method whose visibility attribute is set to the protected visibility.
>
> A protected method can be invoked if and only if the following condition holds:
>
> - Let *M* be an instance of the class `Module` in which the binding of the method exists.
>   *M* is included in the current self, or *M* is the class of the current self or one of its superclasses.
>
> If *M* is a singleton class, whether the method can be invoked or not may be determined in an implementation-defined way.

In particular, pay attention to the last paragraph [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> If *M* is a ***singleton class***, whether the method can be invoked or not may be determined in an ***implementation-defined*** way.

So, the disappointing answer to the question "does this work" is: We don't know. Ruby doesn't say anything about whether or not it works. It depends on the particular implementation.

From the looks of it, it may or may not work, depending on the implementation.

But fear not!

We have the [ruby/spec for singleton classes](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/singleton_class_spec.rb#L53-L56) to our rescue! Here's what it says:

> ```ruby
> describe "A singleton class" do
>   it "is a subclass of a superclass's singleton class" do
>     ClassSpecs::K.singleton_class.superclass.should ==
>       ClassSpecs::H.singleton_class
>   end
> end
> ```

So, it works because the singleton class of the subclass becomes the superclass of the singleton class of the subclass. Let's unpack that.

When I create a subclass of a superclass:

```ruby
class Superclass; end
class Subclass < Superclass; end
```

Then the singleton class of the superclass (`Superclass.singleton_class`) becomes the superclass of the singleton class (`Subclass.singleton_class.superclass`).

Or, in other words, for any class `C`, `C.singleton_class.superclass == C.superclass.singleton_class`. (Excluding, of course, the top class which has no superclass.)

Since the sender (`Subclass`) is an indirect instance (`Subclass` is an instance of its own singleton class `Subclass.singleton_class`, which in turn is a subclass of `Superclass.singleton_class`, therefore `Subclass` is indirectly an instance of `Superclass.singleton_class`) of the module the invoked method is defined in (`Superclass.singleton_class`), invoking a `protected` method is allowed, as per the rules for `protected` accessibility.

Phew.

And since the ruby/spec applies to all implementations of Ruby (unless explicitly stated otherwise using a guard clause), it is guaranteed that this will be the case in all currently maintained versions of all Ruby implementations.

Answer (score 2):

These are *encapsulation controls*. In general you'll want to stick with `protected` to keep "outside"<sup>1</sup> code from messing around with internals, but more importantly, to better control your public interface, and by extension, [*contract*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

Anything `protected` is not intended for use outside of the "family" of that class, so subclasses get access. This is what most code uses as it's generally unconcerned about other subclasses.

The `private` approach is much more specific and restricts access to derived classes as well.

Why would you want to do this? It's situational, but a common reason is you're writing a library and the pattern you're encouraging is to subclass some classes in the library. In order to preserve *encapsulation* some of those methods are `private`.

This means you can those methods in the future without introducing breaking changes for any code dependent on the library. You labeled them `private`, which means "do not use, subject to change without notice".

--

<sup>1</sup> In Ruby you can always find a way to access code even if it's `protected` or `private`, but it is considered rude and/or risky. In other languages like C++ or Java the compiler will generally flat-out refuse any such access. In Ruby you just pull rank.

Comment: Could you provide a short example to illustrate the encapsulation? I noticed that OP wasn't using `private/protected` in the parent class, but didn't have time to write up an illustrative example myself.

Comment: @pjs I think [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) might take too long to explain in this format, though as one of the major design philosophies in so-called "Object Oriented" programming, it's not hard to find out more about it.

Comment: @pjs The parent class does use it, but the indentation is a bit wonky and the use of `class << self` clutters the presentation.